# Getting header data with Sqoop import

Tags: hadoop, teradata, sqoop

I'm importing Teradata table into HDFS which in then will be read by upstream(Datameer in my case).

Datameer expects headers in data before it can read the part files produced by Sqoop, I looked into Sqoop options but can't find anything that gives me data with headers(Column name).

Is it possible to get the table data with column names into HDFS? If not is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need header names when importing files (header detection can be turned off in import jobs). 
Second, Datameer supports direct Teradata import - no need to take the roundtrip via Sqoop.

Comment: Can you tell how header names are turned off?